# Implementing Draggable Pushpin in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

How can I implement draggable pushpin in windows phone 8 Bing map application. Is there any in built method is available for implementing this in windows phone 8?

Comment: Maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591166/wp7-dragging-a-pushpin-on-a-map

Comment: I am looking for a windows phone 8 implementation. I think MS made lots of change in Map control in WP8

Comment: Any reason for down vote ?

Comment: Because it's a "implement this for me!!11" question. The only built-in APIs is the standard map Pushpin functionality as I'm sure you already know about.